# Composer force install package ignore dependency versions

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'd like to install `reliese/laravel` (https://github.com/reliese/laravel/) package into my Laravel 6+ project. `reliese/laravel` requires `"illuminate/support": "~5.1",` but my version is now 6+. I've looked thru the `reliese/laravel` package, and it should still work with 6+. How can I force composer to install this package? I've tried `--ignore-platform-reqs` and that did not work.

Answer (score 6):

From the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) on `require`

- **--ignore-platform-reqs**: ignore `php`, `hhvm`, `lib-*` and `ext-*` requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) config option.

So the flag only ignores machine-specific requirements and not package version mismatch.

I would recommend forking the package on GitHub, manually change the version requirement like so

```json
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "illuminate/support": "~6.0",
        "illuminate/database": "~6.0",
        "illuminate/contracts": "~6.0",
        "illuminate/filesystem": "~6.0",
        "illuminate/console": "~6.0"
    }
}
```

and instruct Composer to pull the package from the fork in your `composer.json`

```json
"require": {
    "reliese/laravel": "master",
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/juventus18/laravel"
    }
]
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, but I don't want to maintain my own repo. This is not an "answer", but a "workaround". Thanks anyway.

Comment: You don't have to maintain a package that hasn't been updated since September last year, but you can [sync your fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork) with the upstream **IF** they have updated it

Comment: instead of forking you could also hand in a PR to allow `"illuminate/support": "~5.1 || ~6.0"`